# Azure pipeline for npm publish does not work as expected

Tags: azure, npm, azure-pipelines, devops, npm-publish

I am a bit new to azure and today I am trying to create a pipeline for publishing `npm package to azure artifactory.`

The issue is - that after pipeline `successfully built`, I can see the published package in the artifacts. However, `published package is almost empty.`
There is only `package.json` and `readme.md.` No dist folder at all.

Here is my Pipeline:

```js
# Node.js
# Build a general Node.js project with npm.
# Add steps that analyze code, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/javascript

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '10.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- script: |
    npm install
    npm run build
    npm publish
  displayName: 'npm install and build and publish'
```

Also, when I build the project locally and run `npm publish` - the package is published as it should,all files in place.

Is there is something I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I found the issue.

The Pipeline definition was actually right, besides one little thing:

```
 versionSpec: '10.x'
```

Version of the Node was incorrect! The pretty old one. Originally the definition was copied from one of the azure official manuals, so the version was from some really old year.

```
 versionSpec: '14.x'
```

And build was successful with all files on their place.

Hope that will be helpful for somebody here.

Answer (score -1):

when publishing packages to npm, you need to authenticate with your credential. You could run it successfully on local because of the .npmrc file saved on your computer. When running `npm publish` on CI, the file doesn't exist, which results in an error. Please try the following steps:

1. Generate an automation access token from this URL: https://www.npmjs.com/
2. Go to your repo, and add a file named "`.npmrc`", enter the content with `//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken={your-token-value}`

Notice:

1. It is recommended to set the access token as an environment variable in [Pipeline library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml).
2. Please use lowercase words as the package's name in `package.json`. Otherwise you will receive a `400 error`.

Comment: "I can see the published package in the artifacts. " It looks like the package creation goes wrong. While your additional hints are useful, they don't seem related to the issue.